# Invalid pointer to forcefully crash the application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

We have a class to represent a list in a very large application:

```
CSMLNode
{
   CSMLNode *pChild;
   CSMLNode *pSibling;  

   CSMLNode()
   {
     pChild = NULL;
     pSibling = NULL;
   }         
}
```

For optimization, the node objects created are kept in a pool and reused over the lifetime of the application. The node objects are released only when the number of node objects exceeds a particular count. When the node objects are released to the pool or taken from the pool, the value of `pChild` and `pSibling` are not set to NULL. We susepect that this is creating crashes in the application.

I am planning to set the value of pChild and pSibling to `0xDDDDDDDD`, if its values are not NULL when taken a node object from the pool. My intensrion is to forcefully crash the application, when `pChild` or `pSibling` pointers are accessed without setting proper object pointers to `pChild` and `pSibling` after taking node object from from the pool.

Will this work as I am expecting? If it doesn't, what pointer value should I give for forceful access violation.

I have enabled full page heap to get the access violation as early as possible.

Comment: Is something preventing you from setting the pointers to NULL during release?

Comment: I am not sure about that. we are analyzing that

Comment: Why don't you set those pointers to appropriate values (NULL or the appropriate other location) when the object is created, independently of whether you null them on release.  Your constructor should not leave you working with random memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Visual Studio debug CRT already does this.  Memory you allocate from the heap is initialized to 0xcdcdcdcd.  Since your struct contains pointers, dereferencing an uninitialized pointer will automatically generate an AV.  The debug heap initialization values are [documented here](http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html).

You don't have to help.  Avoid keeping your own pool, the CRT already does a fine job with ample help from the Windows low-fragmentation heap.  If you want to keep it then I'd suggest you use the same approach as the debug CRT.  Don't skip on everything else it does, the no-man's land areas are an excellent way to detect memory corruption early.

Answer (score 0):

It invokes undefined behaviour, which may or may not crash your application. It may also do other unwanted things.

Even just storing the value `0xDDDDDDDD` as a pointer (without derefencing it) is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Maanu - Some hardware has dedicated address registers which validate pointers. Just getting an invalid value into one of those can kill your program. So the language says it undefined.

Comment: @Maanu: I think the point is that undefined behaviour may very well result in continued execution of the program.